# how can I add a timer to perform periodic housekeeping tasks, to the server-side of my Visual Basic 2013 ASP.NET Web Application project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

In a VB Windows app, I'd use a timer from the Toolbox, but can't find one in ASP.NET toobox.

My project is a web portal, and I need to periodically perform functions, such as weekly generation of invoices, and I don't want to spend extra time creating and maintaining a separate windows app for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to do it:

1. [Simple example of background task using asp.net cache](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/).
2. You can create page that runs your functionality and then create simple win service or powershell script (and add it yo scheduled tasks) to run it.

Keep in mind that if your site is down, your background tasks will be stopped as well. That's why I prefer to implement background tasks as separate part of application.